# PCB antenna radiation pattern

Tags: pcb-antenna

What radiation pattern will this integrated PCB antenna have?

[image: Antenna]
[image: Antenna with dimensions]

Will it be mostly horizontal (XZ plane), or mostly out the top side, or something else?

It's a 2.4GHz module. Datasheet is here:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-42486-atsamr21b18-mz210pa_datasheet.pdf

Comment: That's very hard to say; but even more so, it'll depend on the relative phase of the two feeds, so from the layout alone, even knowing the exact dimensions and material properties, no definite answer could be given.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are any phase offsets more likely than others (e.g. is 180* out of phase easier to build than anything else)? Because I suspect the cheapest phase offset is what the manufacturer has done for this part. And any hints if we assume the "easiest" phase?

Comment: yeah, I'd agree, 180° is the most likely. With that my best guess would be a distorted donut-shaped characteristic with the zero direction being parallell to the 19.7 mm dimension of your board.

Comment: Looks like a form of a folded dipole to me.  With an added stub.  My money would be on a mostly dipole type radiation pattern.